# Should the calendar tag be renamed timekeeping?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

In light of an [upcoming topic challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2833/328) using the tag [calendar](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) I wondered if this tag would benefit from being renamed to [timekeeping](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timekeeping). Calendar might be a more common word, but it rather arbitrarily excludes some topics that would be covered by a timekeeping tag<sup>1</sup>.

I'd suggest renaming [calendar](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) to [timekeeping](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timekeeping), since there seems to be no point in having two tags coexist when one is included by the other but the extra ground isn't massive. Perhaps [calendar](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) should be made a synonym of [timekeeping](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timekeeping) though.

<sub>1: such as a hypothetical "How long would this society's seconds be?" question</sub>

Comment: "calendar" is a much more common word, and there is no common ground in terms of substring matches, so a synonym seems called for if we do go this route.

Comment: FWIW, you seem to be confused as to whether to use the hyphen or not. Which do you prefer? :-)

Comment: If we do rename the tag, I would really like to have a synonym, as most people would tend to add [tag:calendar] naturally.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling whoops, I started by using a hyphen but changed my mind while writing it, seems like I didn't remove the hyphen everywhere.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Vote me, and I'll give you the synonym! ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Is that how we go now? :D If I vote for myself, I might be doing it myself ;-)

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin On a more serious note, I kind of doubt that we have enough time to chisel out a clear community consensus before tomorrow evening, and this *is* one of those things that are much quicker and easier with diamond powers, so a diamond moderator will probably be involved if we choose to do this renaming and synonymization.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, true. At least the new team will have a chance to start off with something light :-)

Answer (score 3):

I agree. Time-keeping is more general, and IMO it would also be more useful than calendar, since this one is quite specific.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. In general, [timekeeping](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timekeeping) is better because it applies to far more situations than [calendar](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar). For example, take a look at this [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26095/im-stranded-on-an-alien-planet-how-do-i-measure-an-earth-year-without-a-clock). [calendar](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) or [timekeeping](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timekeeping)? I, for one, think this question and many others like it are related to time-keeping, rather than calendars, and time-keeping envelops the calendar concept anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Disagree, because language:

Naturally, I would use [timekeeping](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timekeeping) for questions how to track time during a given day.

And [calendar](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) would be used for questions on how to tell what season is